# where are keywodarguments stored def test(t=[]):

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Lets say i have this function:

```
def test(t=[]):
    t.append(1)
    print(t)
```

if i run it a few times the list will be appended like this:

```
test() #[1]
test() #[1, 1]
```

so where is this list stored?
it is not in `globals()` // `locals()` the functions `__dict__` is also empty

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 2):

Okay found it:

It is stored in `__defaults__`

here you can even set it to a different tuple

Comment: *"you can even set it to a different tuple"* For the sanity of *everyone* that will ever need to maintain that code: please DON'T

Comment: @DeepSpace yes im just learning about some inner structures of python. wont use this.

Answer (score -2):

This is because the python interpreter/compiler assigns the default value to the argument at compile time.

That's why default arguments should be immutable.

```
def test(t=None):
    if t is None:
      t = []
    t.append(1)
    print(t)
```

Comment: This is not really what OP is asking. Otherwise, there is [a canonical duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).